# Ограничить ввод текста в textbox определённым набором символов

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли ограничить ввод текста в текстбокс определённым набором символов?

Например, чтобы в текстбокс можно было вводить только буквы [a-z], цифры [0-9] и знаки "-" и "/".

И если есть возможность, то применить это ко всем текстбоксам на форме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете попробовать что то наподобие такого

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        var tb = new TextBox();
        tb.TextChanged += Text_Changed;         
        this.Controls.Add(tb);  
    }

    private static void Text_Changed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb == null) return;     
        var actual = tb.Text;
        var disallowed = @"[^0-9A-Za-z-\/]";
        var newText = Regex.Replace(actual, disallowed, string.Empty);
        if (string.CompareOrdinal(tb.Text, newText)!=0)
        {
            var sstart = tb.SelectionStart;
            tb.Text = newText;
            tb.SelectionStart = sstart-1;
        }       
    }   
}
```

То есть при изменении текста, проверяем его регуляркой и убираем лишнее. Подпишите на это все ваши текстбоксы, если хотите.

Comment: Спасибо большое, это помогло. Подскажите, а возможно ли сделать нечто подобное и для DataGridView? Самостоятельно сделать не выходит.

Comment: @OathOath я не спец по DataGridView, давненько не пользовался winforms, потому вам лучше будет это оформить отдельным вопросом

Answer (score 0):

У каждого символа есть соотвествующий код в таблице `ASCII`.

Все что вам нужно узнать код нужного вам символа.

Повесьте слушателя на изменение в **textbox**, после чего проверяйте соответствует ли введеный пользователем тому символу, что вы не хотите чтоб он вводил, если не соответсвует то добавляйте его к вашему **textbox**, иначе ничего не делайте.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать элемент `MaskedTextBox`. Для того чтобы контролировать вводимые символы, нужно задать в свойстве `Mask` маску. Но если нужен стандартный textBox, то лучше воспользоваться вариантом сверху.

Comment: я могу ошибаться, но вроде в маске для MaskedTextBox указывается количество символов, то есть если в маске только 5 символов, то юзер не введет 10 символов. Но это не точно :)

Comment: @tym32167 Да, вы правы, очень ограниченный контрол)