# Как запретить ввод минуса пока не нажат пробел?

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, textbox, ввод

Есть некоторый textbox, необходимо реализовать запрет ввода знака минус пока не введен пробел
Так, допустим, если необходимо в ручную ввести в textbox данные для массива целых чисел, я хочу избежать подобного
-5-6(необходимо разделять пробелом члены массива, а в данной ситуации выходит что -5-6 это одно число)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ограничить ввод текста в textbox определённым набором символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811338/%d0%9e%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-textbox-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Не надо это запрещать. Пусть пользователь вводит так, как ему удобно. Он может скопипастить готовый набор данных из другого места. И в этом скопированном тексте может не быть пробелов. Юзер отредактирует текст по месту. А вы ему это не позволяете. / Делайте валидацию уже после окончания ввода. Когда фокус перейдет к другому текстбоксу или когда будет нажата какая-нибудь кнопка. Вот тогда и выдавайте юзеру сообщение, что данные невалидны.